# Using eclipse refactoring show error "Could not initialize class org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec$Holder"

Tags: java, eclipse, lucene

When I try to rename class name with refactoring I got error `Could not initialize class org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec$Holder`. Problem occurred in PHP and Python project .

In the log file :

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException


at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:398)<br/>
at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardDialog2.run(RefactoringWizardDialog2.java:319)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard.internalPerformFinish(RefactoringWizard.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.UserInputWizardPage.performFinish(UserInputWizardPage.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard.performFinish(RefactoringWizard.java:710)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardDialog2.okPressed(RefactoringWizardDialog2.java:445)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.buttonPressed(Dialog.java:466)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:618)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:249)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4410)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4228)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3816)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:818)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:794)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation$1.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:188)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:203)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:122)<br/>
    at com.python.pydev.refactoring.refactorer.Refactorer.rename(Refactorer.java:106)<br/>
    at com.python.pydev.refactoring.actions.PyRename.perform(PyRename.java:37)<br/>
    at org.python.pydev.editor.actions.refactoring.PyRefactorAction$Operation.execute(PyRefactorAction.java:68)<br/>
    at org.python.pydev.editor.actions.refactoring.PyRefactorAction$1.runInUIThread(PyRefactorAction.java:178)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:97)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4203)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3819)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:687)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:604)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)<br/>
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)<br/>
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)<br/>
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)<br/>
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)<br/>
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec$Holder<br/>
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec.getDefault(Codec.java:140)<br/>
    at org.apache.lucene.index.LiveIndexWriterConfig.<init>(LiveIndexWriterConfig.java:115)<br/>
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.<init>(IndexWriterConfig.java:163)<br/>
    at org.python.pydev.shared_core.index.IndexApi.init(IndexApi.java:100)<br/>
    at org.python.pydev.shared_core.index.IndexApi.<init>(IndexApi.java:82)<br/>
    at org.python.pydev.shared_core.index.IndexApi.<init>(IndexApi.java:95)<br/>
    at com.python.pydev.analysis.additionalinfo.ReferenceSearchesLucene.internalSearch(ReferenceSearchesLucene.java:157)<br/>
    at com.python.pydev.analysis.additionalinfo.ReferenceSearchesLucene.search(ReferenceSearchesLucene.java:94)<br/>
    at com.python.pydev.analysis.additionalinfo.AdditionalProjectInterpreterInfo.getModulesWithToken(AdditionalProjectInterpreterInfo.java:403)<br/>
    at com.python.pydev.refactoring.refactorer.RefactorerFindReferences.findPossibleReferences(RefactorerFindReferences.java:123)<br/>
    at com.python.pydev.refactoring.wizards.rename.AbstractRenameRefactorProcess.findFilesWithPossibleReferences(AbstractRenameRefactorProcess.java:301)<br/>
    at com.python.pydev.refactoring.wizards.rename.AbstractRenameWorkspaceRefactorProcess.doCheckInitialOnWorkspace(AbstractRenameWorkspaceRefactorProcess.java:164)<br/>
    at com.python.pydev.refactoring.wizards.rename.AbstractRenameWorkspaceRefactorProcess.findReferencesToRenameOnWorkspace(AbstractRenameWorkspaceRefactorProcess.java:135)<br/>
    at com.python.pydev.refactoring.wizards.rename.AbstractRenameRefactorProcess.findReferencesToRename(AbstractRenameRefactorProcess.java:193)<br/>
    at com.python.pydev.refactoring.wizards.rename.PyReferenceSearcher.search(PyReferenceSearcher.java:152)<br/>
    at com.python.pydev.refactoring.wizards.rename.PyRenameEntryPoint.checkFinalConditions(PyRenameEntryPoint.java:268)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.participants.ProcessorBasedRefactoring.checkFinalConditions(ProcessorBasedRefactoring.java:222)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CheckConditionsOperation.run(CheckConditionsOperation.java:83)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CreateChangeOperation.run(CreateChangeOperation.java:119)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation.run(PerformChangeOperation.java:207)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2240)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2267)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:86)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)<br/>
Root exception:<br/>
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec$Holder<br/>
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec.getDefault(Codec.java:140)<br/>
    at org.apache.lucene.index.LiveIndexWriterConfig.<init>(LiveIndexWriterConfig.java:115)<br/>
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.<init>(IndexWriterConfig.java:163)<br/>
    at org.python.pydev.shared_core.index.IndexApi.init(IndexApi.java:100)<br/>
    at org.python.pydev.shared_core.index.IndexApi.<init>(IndexApi.java:82)<br/>
    at org.python.pydev.shared_core.index.IndexApi.<init>(IndexApi.java:95)<br/>
    at com.python.pydev.analysis.additionalinfo.ReferenceSearchesLucene.internalSearch(ReferenceSearchesLucene.java:157)<br/>
    at com.python.pydev.analysis.additionalinfo.ReferenceSearchesLucene.search(ReferenceSearchesLucene.java:94)<br/>
    at com.python.pydev.analysis.additionalinfo.AdditionalProjectInterpreterInfo.getModulesWithToken(AdditionalProjectInterpreterInfo.java:403)<br/>
    at com.python.pydev.refactoring.refactorer.RefactorerFindReferences.findPossibleReferences(RefactorerFindReferences.java:123)<br/>
    at com.python.pydev.refactoring.wizards.rename.AbstractRenameRefactorProcess.findFilesWithPossibleReferences(AbstractRenameRefactorProcess.java:301)<br/>
    at com.python.pydev.refactoring.wizards.rename.AbstractRenameWorkspaceRefactorProcess.doCheckInitialOnWorkspace(AbstractRenameWorkspaceRefactorProcess.java:164)<br/>
    at com.python.pydev.refactoring.wizards.rename.AbstractRenameWorkspaceRefactorProcess.findReferencesToRenameOnWorkspace(AbstractRenameWorkspaceRefactorProcess.java:135)<br/>
    at com.python.pydev.refactoring.wizards.rename.AbstractRenameRefactorProcess.findReferencesToRename(AbstractRenameRefactorProcess.java:193)<br/>
    at com.python.pydev.refactoring.wizards.rename.PyReferenceSearcher.search(PyReferenceSearcher.java:152)<br/>
    at com.python.pydev.refactoring.wizards.rename.PyRenameEntryPoint.checkFinalConditions(PyRenameEntryPoint.java:268)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.participants.ProcessorBasedRefactoring.checkFinalConditions(ProcessorBasedRefactoring.java:222)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CheckConditionsOperation.run(CheckConditionsOperation.java:83)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CreateChangeOperation.run(CreateChangeOperation.java:119)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation.run(PerformChangeOperation.java:207)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2240)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2267)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:86)<br/>
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)<br/>
```

Comment: Please, format you code/exception and read these links to improve your question: [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) | [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This same error also happens in a regular Pydev Search.

Comment: I get the same error now when doing a regular Pydev Search after the latest update of Eclipse to Oxygen... I Should have never updated ...